# Select single row containing unique ID pairs that can be input in reverse

Tags: sql, sqlite, aiosqlite

I have a database that holds one entry for all unique "friendship" pairs. I need a query that will return a single row that matches the pairs. For Example:

friend_id_one = "10987633"
friend_id_two = "01223995"

```
+-------------+-------------+
|id_one       |id_two       |
+------+------+-------------+
|19955220     |01223995     |
+------+------+-------------+
|01223995     |10987633     | <--- Correct Row
+------+------+-------------+
|01223995     |00254987     |
+------+------+-------------+
|01223995     |99774444     |
+------+------+-------------+
|78554412     |01223995     |
+------+------+-------------+
```

The output should be:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|id_one       |id_two       |
+------+------+-------------+
|01223995     |10987633     | <--- Correct Row
+------+------+-------------+
```

My issue is that multiple users can have multiple unique friend pairs. The first ID is always the users that initiates the friendship. But, the order of the IDs when input can be reversed. Say, the friend whose ID belongs to id_two submits a query, the order of the variables would be inverse.

Example: friend_one gives a gift to friend_two. The first ID is always the person taking action, therefore the argument order would be friend_one and friend_two. But, if friend_two gives the gift the argument order would be friend_two and friend_one.

To sum up, I need to return as single row containing unique pairing for this to work properly. I have tried this:

```
 SELECT * FROM friends WHERE
      (friend_one_id=? OR friend_two_id=?) AND (friend_one_id=? OR
      friend_two_id=?), (friend_one.user_id, friend_two_id,
      friend_two_id,friend_one.user_id,)
```

This obviously failed and returned nothing. Scratching my head as to how this might work.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you tag it? Answers may vary materially between each.

Comment: `sqlite` from the `aiosqlite` Python module.

Comment: where do you get the friend ids from? is there another input table? @xxSithRagexx

Comment: The friend ID comes from a function. This is a Discord bot, so the `author` will always be the first ID when the record is created. The person they are targeting to gift will be the second. The issue is, when the second person gives a gift back, I need to find the original row entry.

Comment: what about storing the gifts? so that if B gives a gift back to A, you can query that table @xxSithRagexx

Comment: Correct. It all queries that table to see if a unique pair exists. I might have just figured it out. If this is functioning correctly, I'll post the answer.

Comment: It should all function off one row entry. The other columns track the points awarded for gifting between the pairs and the friendship level. So, if you find one row that matches A AND B or B AND A then it's the only row that would exist for the pair. My application checks to see if the pair exists before allowing a pair to be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually very close to solving this. The solution was:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE
  (friend_one_id=? AND friend_two_id=?) OR (friend_one_id=? AND
  friend_two_id=?), (friend_one.user_id, friend_two_id,
  friend_two_id,friend_one.user_id,)
```